# Moving text from right to left

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I'm working on a Roblox game, I want a `TextLabel` to move from right to left repeatadly and smoothly.
Something like  this:
https://youtu.be/9f7xAxKtjXc

I have already tried to tween the `Textlabel` on hiting corner it will restart but it wasn't smooth.
I'm expecting the TextLabel to move from right to left smoothly as in the video above.

Code I have tried:

```
local text = {script.Parent.TextLabel}

while wait() do
   for _,v in pairs(text) do
    local temp = v.Position.X.Scale
    if (temp <= -v.Size.X.Scale) then
       temp = 1.0
       end
       v.Position = UDim2.new(temp - 0.01, 0, 0.2, 0)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local text = {script.Parent.TextLabel}

while wait() do
    for _,v in pairs(text) do
        local temp = v.Position.X.Scale
        if (temp + 1.22 <= -v.Size.X.Scale) then
            temp = -0.016
        end
        v.Position = UDim2.new(temp - 0.01, 0, 0.2, 0)
    end
end
```

Change the TextLabel size to `{0, 3298},{0, 70}` and using this code it will be really smooth, just tweaked the values a little and it worked.